# distance from calibration target to the camera in camera calibration

Tags: opencv, camera, camera-calibration

If the working distance of the camera is from 0.2M to 2M, How should I choose the distance from the calibration target to the camera when I calibration the camera? What does the distance affect the calibration?

Comment: Tell us about the calibration procedure you are using and what is your main goal with it...

Comment: I am using Zhang's method from OpenCV to perform camera calibration.